# multiple sql in python

Tags: python, mysql

i am trying to send two SQL ( select and update) in one python file. but getting still error

```
  cursor = cnx.cursor()
  query = "select id, mail from `candidats`; UPDATE candidats SET statusmail=1 "
  results = cursor.execute(query, multi=True)
  for cur in results:
    print('cursor:', cur)
    print('result:', cur.fetchall())
  cursor.close()
  cnx.close()
```

getting this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from
```

Comment: Did you get an Error when you execute the two querys seperated?

Comment: Send your select queries separately if you want to fetch results.

Comment: An UPDATE will not produce results?

Comment: Yes, seperated sql, the UPDATE not affect table ( no change )

Comment: cnx.commit()  was missed, it work now